# H2O.ai mini_batch_size is really used?

Tags: neural-network, h2o, mini-batch

In the documentation of H2O is written:

> mini_batch_size: Specify a value for the mini-batch size. (Smaller values lead to a better fit; larger values can speed up and generalize better.)

but when I run a model using the FLOW UI (with mini_batch_size > 1) in the log file is written:

> WARN: _mini_batch_size Only mini-batch size = 1 is supported right now.

so the question: is the mini_batch_size really used??

Comment: pls provide the documentation *link*

Comment: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html?highlight=mini_batch_size

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a left over from preparation for a DeepWater integration that never happened. E.g. https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/search?l=Java&p=2&q=mini_batch_size

That makes sense, because the Hogwild! algorithm, that H2O's deep learning uses, does away with the need for batching training data.

To sum up, I don't think it is used.